# Django queryset exclude regex

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a command that filter through requests, and I need to extract some of them following two rules.

It should

```
include '^https?:\/\/[^.]*\.?site\.co([^?]*[?]).*utm_.*$'
or
exclude '^https?:\/\/[^.]*\.?site\.([^\/]+\/)*'
```

So, working out a possible SQL representation, I came up with:

```
exclude (
   matching '^https?:\/\/[^.]*\.?site\.([^\/]+\/)*'
   and
   not matching '^https?:\/\/[^.]*\.?site\.co([^?]*[?]).*utm_.*$'
)
```

Which translate in django to:

```
.exclude(
   Q(referer__iregex=r'^https?:\/\/[^.]*\.?site\.co([^?]*[?]).*utm_.*$') &
   Q(referer__not_iregex=r'^https?://[^.]*\.?site\.[^/]+/?[\?]*$'))
```

But unfortunately, the `__not_iregex` lookup doesn't exists. What could be a workaround this?

Comment: Have you tried using `filter` for one and `exclude` for the other. That might work around the `not` part. Surely, you also move the negation into the regex itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could in fact use `filter` for the part which you don't want to exclude:

```
queryset
    .filter(referer__iregex=r'^https?://[^.]*\.?site\.[^/]+/?[\?]*$')
    .exclude(referer__iregex=r'^https?:\/\/[^.]*\.?site\.([^\/]+\/)*')
```

So here your `matching` goes into `exclude` and `not matching` goes into `filter`.

Or you could use the `~Q` if you really want to imitate what you have in the SQL representation:

```
.exclude(
   Q(referer__iregex=r'^https?:\/\/[^.]*\.?site\.([^\/]+\/)*') &
   ~Q(referer__iregex=r'^https?://[^.]*\.?site\.[^/]+/?[\?]*$'))
   # notice use of ~ here
```